# Как проверить пользователя на админ права Телеграм C#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу админ бота для Телеграма и мне нужно проверить пользователя на админ права, и если он не просто участник а админ, то код должен работать, в моем случае это команда кика

вот сам код:

`switch (message.Text)
 {
    case "/kick":
    {
       await Bot.KickChatMemberAsync(message.Chat.Id, userId: message.ReplyToMessage.From.Id);
    }
    break;
 }`

он рабочий , но когда просто пользователь использует команду, vs выдает ошибку и останавливает работу, я знаю что есть метод "ChatMemberStatus", но не пойму как его использовать.

Почитал Api, полазил по сайтам, нашел что-то похожее но и на него тоже ругается.

Comment: есть метод GetChatMemberAsync, который возвращает Status по нему можно проверить является ли пользователь Admin/Creator в данном чате

Comment: @eXit , я дописал в коде вот такое :
`
switch (message.Text)
            {
                
                case "/kick":
                        
                        {
                        var admin = Bot.GetChatMemberAsync(message.Chat.Id, userId: message.From.Id).Result;
if (admin.Status == ChatMemberStatus.Administrator)                        await 
Bot.KickChatMemberAsync(message.Chat.Id, userId: message.ReplyToMessage.From.Id);
                        }
break;
} `

он говорит что не указана ссылка на экземпляр